# How can I increase the number of retires/attempts for Google Authenticator?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, passwords, authentication

I believe libpam-google-authenticator module in my ubuntu server blocks ssh for sometime when the password or verification code is incorrectly entered for 3 or 4 times by a user. How can I increase the number of tries?

I have the below files in my /etc/pam.d

```
atd
chfn
chpasswd
chsh
common-account
common-auth
common-password
common-session
common-session-noninteractive
cron
login
newusers
other
passwd
polkit-1
runuser
runuser-l
sshd
su
sudo
systemd-user
vmtoolsd
```

Within 3 or 4 wrong tries, this comes in auth.log

```
Aug 28 11:45:07 Bastion sshd[20639]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  user=username
Aug 28 11:45:09 Bastion sshd[20574]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for username from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Aug 28 11:45:10 Bastion sshd[20640]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  user=username
```

Please help me.

Comment: Just so you know, strictly limiting the number of attempts is required for security because the possible codes are limited.  Increasing it above single digits is a security problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue. It was OSSEC. I had an ossec-hids agent also installed in the server. The active-response feature in the ossec was blocking IP for ssh failures. It was fixed by adding the IP to be ignored inside <white_list>1.2.3.4</white_list> in a global block. Thanks for all the helpful tips guys.